# How to prevent Json.NET from using use default values for missing constructor parameters while still using default values for properties?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

Is there a way to tell JSON.net that when it attempts to deserialize using a constructor (if there is no default constructor), that it should NOT assign default value to constructor parameters and that it should only call a constructor if every constructor parameter is represented in the JSON string?  This same serializer SHOULD use default values when calling property/field setters, the rule is only scoped to constructors.  None of the enum values here seem to be appropriate: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DefaultValueHandling.htm

**The solution should NOT rely on applying any attributes to the types being deserialized.**

for example, the json string `"{}"` will deserialize to an object of type `Dog` by setting the Dog's age to 0 (the default value for an int).  I'd like to a generalized, not-attribute-based solution to prevent this from happening.  In this case, `{"age":4}` would work because `age` is specified in the JSON string and corresponds to the constructor parameter.

```
public class Dog
{
    public Dog(int age)
    {
        this.Age = age;
    }

    public int Age { get; }
}
```

However, if `Dog` is specified as such, then `"{}"` *should* deserialize to a Dog with Age == 0, because the Dog is not being created using a constructor.

```
public class Dog
{   
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

As to "why would you want to do this"... Objects with constructors are typically qualitatively different than POCOs as it relates to their properties.  Using a constructor to store property values instead of settable properties on a POCO typically means that you want to validate/constrain the property values.  So it's reasonable not to allow deserialization with default values in the presence of constructor(s).

Comment: Could you provide a sample code with current vs desired behavior?

Comment: @IsmailHawayel - +1! Example added! sorry for not including it originally

Comment: So in your first example, if `Dog` has a constructor that accepts an `int` but the json string is `{}`, what should happen?  Throw an exception?  Make the dog null?

Comment: @BrianRogers - it should throw an exception, or more specifically `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dog>(jsonString)` should throw

Comment: And what if the Dog has more than one constructor?  How do we know which constructor to use?

Comment: From you exemple, if the dog has an "age" constructor parameter and also an "age" property, what should json.net do? Call the constructor with the right property, then not the property. Or call a default constructor then the property. Or call the right constructor then also the property. That's a lot of choices to make, and none is the obvious "right" one. In such a case, a good tool should not make assumptions on what the user want. That's far too risky.

Comment: @BrianRogers - If there's more than one constructor then json.NET should do whatever it's doing now.  Looking for the constructor with the most number of matches?  Least number?  My types typically don't have multiple constructors because I typically find that its a code smell, but good question for completeness.

Comment: @SFun28 : you find that constructor overloading is a code smell? I tend to strongly disagree. Constructor overloading without the overloads chaining into each other is a code smell, but a constructor with less parameters calling the one with more parameters is just good practice.

Comment: @Falanwe - I'm confused - if there's a constructor parameter (and thus a constructor) then how can json.net call the default constructor?  There is no default constructor.  If there's a constructor then JSON.net has to use the constructor to new-up the object.  After that, any remaining, unmapped properties would be mapped to the type's properties.

Comment: @SFun28 - what is a code smell in my book is using serialization library on a class that has a meaningful parametrized constructor. If your object is "intelligent enough" to justify a non-trivial constructor, it's probably not a good candidate to be a DTO or to be persisted directly.

Comment: @SFun28 : you can have both a parameterless constructor and a parameterized one on the same object. And json.net can always call a parameterized constructor with default parameters.

Comment: @Falanwe - the code smell is that your object is possibly trying to do/encapsulate too much.  Agreed that it's a smell to not use chaining when you can, but before you even get there you have to ask yourself whether the object has too much responsibiliy/state/etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112815/discussion-between-sfun28-and-falanwe).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When Json.NET encounters an object without a parameterless constructor but with a parameterized constructor, it will call that constructor to create the object, [matching the JSON property names to the constructor arguments by name using reflection](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConstructorAttribute.htm) via a case-insensitive best match algorithm.  I.e. a property whose name also appears in the constructor will be set via the constructor call, not the set method (even if there is one).

Thus, you can mark a constructor argument as required by marking the equivalent property as [required](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_Required.htm):

```
public class Dog
{
    public Dog(int age)
    {
        this.Age = age;
    }

    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public int Age { get; }
}
```

Now `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dog>(jsonString)` will throw when the `"age"` property is missing.

Since this is something you *always* want, you can create a [custom contract resolver](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm) inheriting from [`DefaultContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver.htm) or [`CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.htm) that marks properties passed to the constructor as required automatically, without the need for attributes:

```
public class ConstructorParametersRequiredContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreatePropertyFromConstructorParameter(JsonProperty matchingMemberProperty, ParameterInfo parameterInfo)
    {
        var property = base.CreatePropertyFromConstructorParameter(matchingMemberProperty, parameterInfo);

        if (property != null && matchingMemberProperty != null)
        {
            var required = matchingMemberProperty.Required;
            // If the member is already explicitly marked with some Required attribute, don't override it.
            // In Json.NET 12.0.2 and later you can use matchingMemberProperty.IsRequiredSpecified to check to see if Required is explicitly specified.
            // if (!matchingMemberProperty.IsRequiredSpecified) 
            if (required == Required.Default)
            {
                if (matchingMemberProperty.PropertyType != null && (matchingMemberProperty.PropertyType.IsValueType && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(matchingMemberProperty.PropertyType) == null))
                {
                    required = Required.Always;
                }
                else
                {
                    required = Required.AllowNull;
                }
                // It turns out to be necessary to mark the original matchingMemberProperty as required.
                property.Required = matchingMemberProperty.Required = required;
            }
        }

        return property;
    }
}
```

Then construct an instance of the resolver:

```
static IContractResolver requiredResolver = new ConstructorParametersRequiredContractResolver();
```

And use it as follows:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = requiredResolver };
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString, settings)
```

Now deserialization will throw if the `"age"` property is missing from the JSON.

Notes:

- This only works if there *is* a corresponding property.  There doesn't appear to be a straightforward way to mark a constructor parameter with no corresponding property as required.
- Newtonsoft recommends that you [cache and reuse the contract resolver for best performance](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#ReuseContractResolver).

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KaLsil).

Comment: Thanks so much for writing this up!  On your last comment...so what would happen if there is a constructor parameter with no corresponding property?  Does json.net stll attempt construction with the default value for that parameter?  Or does it throw?

Comment: @SFun28 - I just checked.  If there is a property in the JSON with the same name as a constructor parameter, then even if there is no equivalent c# property it will deserialize and pass the value using the type of the constructor argument.  Otherwise Json.NET will pass a default value.

Comment: You could make the `CreatePropertyFromConstructorParameter()` override throw if there's no matching property, if you want. If it is rare to be missing the equivalent property, you can add a private property and mark it with [JsonProperty] in those few cases.