# Is there a way to check if a c# class is json serializable and deserializable

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, .net-4.8

I have a project with about 200 classes which need to be saved as json and deserialized back later.
All the classes are immutable and due to this fact I need to inject all complex types into the constructor, otherwise deserialization does not work. Because I use a Clonable base class I don't initialize every parameter in the constructor. When I forget to add a single class to the construtor or misspell it, deserialization does not work anymore and the only way I know to check is to write a lot of unit tests with sample data.

This is a sample to reproduce my problem:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var immutableClass = new ImmutableClass(new OtherImmutableClass(2)).WithAnyProperty(1);
    var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(immutableClass, Formatting.Indented);
    var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ImmutableClass>(jsonString);
}

public class ImmutableClass : Clonable<ImmutableClass>
{
    public ImmutableClass(OtherImmutableClass otherImmutableClassInstance)
    {
        OtherImmutableClassInstance = otherImmutableClassInstance;
    }

    public OtherImmutableClass OtherImmutableClassInstance { get; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public int AnyProperty { get; private set; }

    public ImmutableClass WithAnyProperty(int newValue)
    {
        return With(s => s.AnyProperty = newValue);
    }
}

public class OtherImmutableClass
{
    public OtherImmutableClass(int completelyWrongPropertyName)
    {
        MyProperty = completelyWrongPropertyName;
    }

    public int MyProperty { get; }
}

public abstract class Clonable<T> where T : Clonable<T>
{
    protected T With(Action<T> updateAction)
    {
        var clone = (T)MemberwiseClone();
        updateAction(clone);
        return clone;
    }
}
```

After serialization the content of my jsonString is as expected:

```
{
  "OtherImmutableClassInstance": {
    "MyProperty": 2
  },
  "AnyProperty": 1
}
```

When I deserialize no Exception is thrown but the `MyProperty` is 0 instead of 2 because of `completelyWrongPropertyName` does not match `MyProperty` in the constructor of `OtherImmutableClass`.

Is there an easy way to check if my model is serializable and deserializable without writing UnitTests for each class?

I am searching something like `JsonChecker<ImmutableClass>.CanSerializeAndDeserialize();`

I already asked google but found no solution.

Comment: What does serializability have to do with whether you misspelled something?

Comment: BTW, your code on DotNetFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HAsobi

Comment: Isn't your main problem with `OtherImmutableClass` the fact that you don't have a parameterless constructor, or haven't marked the constructor you do have with `[JsonConstructor]` so the deserializer knows to use it?  I don't think "misspelling" has anything to do with it.

Comment: Anyway, I doubt there is any easy way to get what you want.  It's up to you to define whether serialization/deserialization 'worked' or not for your classes, because it's you who created them.  Unit testing is likely the best way to define success for yourself.

Comment: Testing whether a class "is serializable" by Json.NET is kind of vague an open-ended.  (Just seeing whether Json.NET can construct the object is nontrivial; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41871975/3744182)) for the algorithm.)  However, if you just want to ensure every constructor parameter has an equivalent property, then that's straightforward. See [How to throw an exception when JsonConstructor parameter name doesn't match JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63898984/3744182) for how.