# How can I get Newtonsoft.Json to throw an exception when deserializing an object with a property missing from the constructor?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have an object with one constructor that has a parameter name that does not match the property name. Because the parameter name doesn't match, Newtonsoft deserializes it to an object with the default value. I get why that happens and I know I can fix it by changing the parameter name or by making the property `{ get; set; }`, but I'm surprised that `MissingMemberHandling.Error` does not catch the issue. Is there another setting that will cause this to throw an exception?

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
// Runnable in LINQPad

void Main()
{
    JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;

    // Expected: throw an exception
    var foo = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>("{a:123,c:456}", settings);

    // Actual: foo.A is 0 and C is 456
    Console.WriteLine(foo);
}


public class Foo
{
    public Foo(int b, int c)
    {
        A = b;
        C = c;
    }
    
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public int A { get; }
    public int C { get; }
}
```

Comment: But thats just an argument to your constructor - what are you *really* trying to achieve? Anyone can call their constructor arguments anything.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Exactly, anyone can (and does) call their constructor arguments anything. I want to throw an exception if deserialization had to pick a default value in case someone names something in a way that the library doesn't like. That way, we catch the error early and don't have to spend time tracking down a bug.

Comment: But your argument is for **you** - nobody else even cares about it other than passing arguments in the right order

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I just finished tracking down a bug caused by this issue and wish Newtonsoft would have warned me it was picking a default value because it couldn't correlate the constructor parameter with the property name.

Comment: Serializers almost always use the simple/parameterless constructor mainly because they do not know what those parameters (*not* properties*) do.  FGor one thing, using properties as parameters would require 'reading ahead' to get values(s).  Properties are then set individually.

Comment: Newtonsoft can and does use a constructor when you have get-only properties. If the parameter name was `a` instead of `b` this would work.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp I added a bit more to the example to show how it can work correctly.

Comment: why bother with a constructor that has no logic? why not eliminate the constructor and the let the MissingMemberHandling enum do its thing?

Comment: Because I want an immutable object. Without the constructor I would need `{ get; set; }` properties.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [How to throw an exception when JsonConstructor parameter name doesn't match JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63898984/3744182), agree?  That question deals specifically with an unmatched constructor parameter that the OP wants to mark as required.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp - *using properties as parameters would require 'reading ahead' to get values(s).* - this is in fact implemented by Json.NET.  When a parameterized constructor is used, Json.NET reads ahead, deserializes all the properties and constructor arguments, then finally constructs the object.  See e.g. [How does JSON deserialization in C# work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41871975/3744182) or [JSON.net: how to deserialize without using the default constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23017716/3744182).

Comment: @dbc I think you're right, that does answer my question. Thanks!